# How much linguistics is within the scope of our site?

Tags: discussion, scope

On some other sites I've seen questions commented that they should wait for the proposed Linguistics site.

What about us? Do we cover all aspects of the Japanese language down into the depths of linguistics or should we draw the line somewhere?

If we do allow linguistics how about [synchronic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronic_analysis_%28linguistics%29) and [diachronic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_linguistics) linguistics?

Comment: Although this question got little attention, this other question has a different view: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/378/is-this-forum-for-japanese-learners-or-language-learners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it is linguistics applied to Japanese (and not a digression on the general field of linguistics), I see no reason to restrict it in any way.

**Addendum:** Any Japanese-related linguistics is fair game... *but* in case arcane (or not so arcane but likely unknown to the *hoi poloi*) linguistic terms are used, appropriate linking or short explanation would be nice.

Comment: I agree and I've asked an example question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/is-japanese-really-an-agglutinative-language

Comment: @hippietrail: and reading your question made me think of my addendum :-)

Comment: @hippietrail: In the context of your question, for example, a quick sentence explaining what agglutinative languages are, would allow even casual users to follow the conversation without having to dig into a linguistics textbook.

Comment: I thought I did. The part about "slots" and endings. I'll read up how Wikipedia defines the terms though and see if I can do better. (-: