# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This question is copied from [several](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline) [other](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/909/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline) StackExchange network [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline) sites.

Now that we've gone through several discussions that refine the scope of JLU, I think we're ready to put our copywriter's hat on and have fun coming up with charming elevator pitches/taglines/mottos.

- [Who is our target audience?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-our-target-audience)
- [Should uniquely cultural questions be acceptable?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/should-uniquely-cultural-questions-be-acceptable)
- [Is this forum for Japanese learners or language learners?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378/is-this-forum-for-japanese-learners-or-language-learners)

Hopefully some of the compelling ones will find its way into the new site design when we graduate beta (though not guaranteed). Even if that doesn't happen, we can always use our favorite ones when introducing JLU to other people.

---

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

---

Portions that referred to domain names have been removed from the question.

Answer (score 4):

I could propose my tongue-in-cheek version I mentioned in chat:

> It depends on context

It's awful as an elevator pitch... but great as an inside joke

Answer (score 3):

To get the ball rolling...

**motto**

> Know your aiueo's.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about a good elevator pitch for JLSE since it's listed as one of [the 7 essential questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta).

> The *Japanese Language Stack Exchange* is an online forum compromised of Japanese learners, native speakers, and linguists, and contains in-depth Q&A regarding subtleties of the language, such as word choice, advanced grammar, etymology, and more.

I tried to cover all the things that make me really love this site:

- **the diversity**: having native speakers helps with accuracy, having linguists helps with discovering underlying rules (aiding memorization), and having plain ol' learners helps with keeping things understandable.
- **the depth**: our community rewards answers which don't sweep details under the rug, and especially so when the details end up forming a beautiful coherent picture.
- **the versatility**: personally, I can only really answer grammar-related questions, but am continuously awed by the other questions which I couldn't even  ask, let alone answer, making the site great not only for increasing depth of knowledge but breadth of it as well.